# Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements when tried to set a return value with lifetime to a struct

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
pub struct SumAggregator<'ctx> {
    input: i32,
    state: Cell<Option<IntValue<'ctx>>>,
}

impl<'ctx> SumAggregator<'ctx> {
    pub fn new() -> SumAggregator<'ctx> {
        SumAggregator {
            input: 0,
            state: Cell::new(None),
        }
    }
}

impl<'ctx> Aggregator for SumAggregator<'ctx> {
    fn init(&self, generator: &Generator, layout: &mut Layout, idx: i32) {
        let col_type = generator.context.i32_type();
        self.state.set(Some(col_type.const_int(0, true)));
        generator.build_debug("initialized state value:", self.state.get().unwrap().as_basic_value_enum());
    }

    fn process(&self, val: IntValue) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Above is the core code which throws this error. `col_type.const_int(0, true)` can return a `IntValue` with a 'ctx lifetime. When I tried to set this value to my struct, this error occured. I am new to Rust. As far as I know, only references could cause lifetime problem. However, in my use case, I just want to put a value not a reference to a struct(even though this value has a lifetime).

Here is the error stack:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/operator/groupby/mod.rs:40:42
   |
40 |         let col_type = generator.context.i32_type();
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the method body at 37:5...
  --> src/operator/groupby/mod.rs:37:5
   |
37 |     fn init(&self, generator: &Generator, layout: &mut Layout, idx: i32) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/operator/groupby/mod.rs:40:24
   |
40 |         let col_type = generator.context.i32_type();
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'ctx` as defined on the impl at 36:6...
  --> src/operator/groupby/mod.rs:36:6
   |
36 | impl<'ctx> Aggregator for SumAggregator<'ctx> {
   |      ^^^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/operator/groupby/mod.rs:41:24
   |
41 |         self.state.set(Some(col_type.const_int(0, true)));
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Option<inkwell::values::IntValue<'ctx>>`
              found `Option<inkwell::values::IntValue<'_>>`
```

Comment: What's `IntValue`? If you look into it, you will probably see that it holds a reference…

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `SumAggregator` wants to have an `IntValue` that lives at least as long as itself. But in the `init` function you are trying to give it an `IntValue` that lives only until the end of the `init` function.

You can make sure that the `IntValue` lives long enough by specifying the `Generator`'s reference's lifetime:

```rust
impl<'ctx> Aggregator for SumAggregator<'ctx> {
    fn init(&self, generator: &'ctx Generator, layout: &mut Layout, idx: i32) {
        // col_type is &'ctx IntType
        let col_type = generator.context.i32_type();

        // int_value is &'ctx IntValue
        let int_value = col_type.const_int(0, true)

        // putting &'ctx IntValue into &'ctx IntValue
        self.state.set(Some(int_value));

        generator.build_debug("initialized state value:", self.state.get().unwrap().as_basic_value_enum());
    }

    ...
}
```

Without doing that it is the same as:

```rust
impl<'ctx> Aggregator for SumAggregator<'ctx> {
    fn init<'a, 'b>(&self, generator: &'a Generator, layout: &'b mut Layout, idx: i32) {
        // col_type is &'a IntType
        let col_type = generator.context.i32_type();

        // int_value is &'a IntValue
        let int_value = col_type.const_int(0, true)

        // trying to put &'a IntValue into &'ctx IntValue
        self.state.set(Some(int_value));

        generator.build_debug("initialized state value:", self.state.get().unwrap().as_basic_value_enum());
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specific all of lets for example:

```
let int_value:IntValue<'ctx> = col_type.const_int(0, true)
```

And repeat it for Option and cell left-s.

Consider to a,b,ctx they need more management and if it is possible try it once:

```
impl<'a,'b,'ctx>
```